# Force.com Sites v/s Customer Community

Tags: force.com-sites

I am looking for some thoughts and inputs on the problem statement that I've.

Problem statement - Force.com sites versus Customer Community

I need to design a portal which will be used by around 100K users. This needs to happen on the Salesforce.com platform. The portal also needs to work from a mobile stand point.
This portal will essentially be used to fill tax forms, make payments, see their application status, etc.

The portal will also have a set of Admin users where they can configure different forms, set alerts, send email notifications, etc.

This is a full suite of customization which I believe is hard to configure, customize on the Community and hence my first thoughts is a Force.com site.

The portal/website also needs to have a login, authentication in place.

1. How will this be handled using a Force.com site?
2. I would also like to know if we choose Force.com site then what would be the Salesforce licensing scenario as I need authentication also in place?
3. I also assume that I would be able to leverage the Lightning design system to design the UI/UX part.
4. Can java script frameworks like Angular JS work in conjunction with Lightning design system framework?

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Force.com site and communities have different licensing implications. At the moment I would say go with communities but what "forms" are they? What are the Salesforce objects that you will be saving these forms? Will the portal users need to edit them after? I say this because with sites users can (eg) only create opportunities not edit them etc..

Comment: All custom objects, yes the portal users need to edit them.

Comment: Mind if I ask what you went with in the end? I am currently considering options for a similar project.